# Creating a calculated field based on row values provided column values match

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a `pandas dataframe`, US state temperature data that is grouped firstly by **State** and then by **Year**. I have already selected the first and last years of entries by subsetting the original dataframe. I want to create a new `dataframe` that shows the difference in **AvgTemperature** from the first year (1995) and the last year (2019) for all 50 states.

| State | Year | AvgTemperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alabama | 1995 | 63.66 |
| Alabama | 2019 | 66.32 |
| Alaska | 1995 | 35.97 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to have a result that I can plot to show which states have changed the most over time, preferably in the format simply of **State** as column 1 and **Temperature_Change** as column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `pivot`, compute the `diff` and plot as bar:

```
(df.pivot('State', 'Year', 'AvgTemperature')
   .diff(axis=1)
   .iloc[:,-1]
   .rename('diff')
   .plot.bar()
 )
```

*NB. I used dummy data for Alaska in 2019.*

Output:

[image]

Comment: This not only works but is also a better way to visualize the data than I had asked for help for... so double thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.sort_values(['State', 'Year']).groupby('State').apply(lambda g: g.iloc[-1]['AvgTemperature'] - g.iloc[0]['AvgTemperature'])
```